# Ubuntu One folder vs Checking the "sync with ubuntu one" check box

Tags: ubuntu-one, folder

What is the difference between dragging a folder over to the Ubuntu One folder for syncing and just checking the "synchronize this folder" check box on each folder I want to sync?

Answer (score 2):

The "Ubuntu One" is the default folder, that is always synced when you enable Ubuntu One. For other synced folders, you can select in each devices which to sync or not sync.

For example:

- on PC "A" you have "Ubuntu One" folder, and Pictures folder; you select "Pictures" for syncing.
- on PC "B" you also enable Ubuntu One service: the "Ubuntu One" folder will be synced, but you can avoid to select also "Pictures" syncing.